# Can JFrog Artifactory host binaries instead of an s3 server, when working with cocoapods?

Tags: cocoapods, artifactory

We are not currently using cocoapods, but would like to start using it with JFrog Artifactory. We have a Swift framework that needs to be delivered to our clients by permission only.

How can I use JFrog Artifactory to host my Swift Framework's, and be consumed by our clients?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JFrog Artifactory supports hosting [CocoaPods repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/CocoaPods+Repositories).
Please notice that this requires the Pro/Enterprise version of the product.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to get it working in the trial period?

Comment: What is Custom URL Base? It's a URL prefix pointing to where?

Comment: Yes, it will work in a trial period (as any other feature). You can read more about custom base URL here - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Artifactory